# How to update my map with the restored features from JSON format?

Tags: geojson, features, openlayers

I'm trying to implement a CRUD that have a map OpenLayers.

1. First, I drawed and saved the features with writeFeatures().
2. Second, I'm trying to show the polygon that I drawed, and here is my problem:

- After I set the map.setLayer my map doesn't show the features.
  I would like that when I select the product in the list, my map show the features that I read from my database, in format JSON. I saved using WriteFeatures();
- Could I need a loop to iterate each item of array?

What am I doing wrong?

My configuration:

- Laravel v6.18.22 with bootstrap;
- OpenLayers v6.3.1

In my HTML has:

```
<div id="map" class="map" </div>

  <script>
    const getFeatur = @json(route('homeController.getLavouras'));
  </script>

 <script type="application/javascript" >
  my_map.display();
 </script>
```

In my external JavaScript file (my_map.js) has:

```
    import 'ol/ol.css';
    import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
    import Geolocation from 'ol/Geolocation';
    import Map from 'ol/Map';
    import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
    import View from 'ol/View';
    import {Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style';
    import {OSM, Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source';
    import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';
    import VectorContext from 'ol/render/VectorContext';
    import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';    
var my_map = {                       // <-- add this line to declare the object
    display: function () {           // <-- add this line to declare a method 
      
      var view = new View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-49.450270, -15.496072]),
        zoom: 6 ,
      });
      
      var map = new Map({
        layers: [
          new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM(),
          }) ],
        target: 'map',
        view: view,
      });
      
      new VectorLayer({
        map: map,
        source: new VectorSource()
      });
       
document.getElementById('produtoid').onchange = function(){
var produtoid = document.getElementById('produtoid').value; 
var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
        $.ajax({
                        url:getFeatur,
                        method:"GET",
                        data:{produtoid:produtoid, _token:_token},
                        success:function(result)
                        {             
 
                          var newSource = new ol.source.Vector({
                                        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                                        features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(result.dados[0].feature, 
                                            {
                                                dataProjection: 'EPSG:26918',
                                                featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
                                             }),
                                        });

                          
                          var nwLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                              title: 'My Title',
                              source: newSource,     
                              visible: true,
                          });         
                          map.addLayer(nwLayer); --> I think that here my map has to refresh and show the features. 
                          
                      }            
                  });
                }


}                                // <-- close the method
};                                   // <-- close the object
export default my_map;               // <-- and export the object
```

Comment: Your code contains a mix of module imports and full build syntax, so you are probably getting errors with 
`ol.proj.fromLonLat` `ol.source.Vector` `ol.format.GeoJSON` and `ol.layer.Vector`

Comment: But nothing errors in Console.log. When I put a return ajax variable to Console.log, I see a JSON format, exemple:   {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-13027197.585166512,5415923.420611887],[-13026918.952481057,5427423.809086096],[-13028401.839417916,5434583.655001746],[-13027345.306130797,5439431.734050472],[-13025439.516448416,5440697.514279615],[-13026075.596018808,5442735.2890267335],[-13022686.028843643,5443720.071568927],[-13021837.663004309,5445899.96656019],[-13021836.772448381,5450683.865034185],[-1

Comment: Mike, can you give me how most I do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of map refreshing when it comes to OpenLayers, I think in your case style property is missing in the vector layer object

example vector layer looks like this -

```
  source: new VectorSource(),
  map: map,
  style: new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
      width: 2,
    }),
  }),
});
```

You can refer to this link here - [Vector Layer in OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html)

Also, you can just update the source of the vector layer, it will reflect on the map directly, and you don't need to create a new layer every time.